# Randomization of a list

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2007

I have a list of 20,000 students who are listed basis their academic standing in an excel sheet - undergraduate, graduate, PhD, part-time. I would like to get a random list of students. I can use the RAND function to create a list of random, however, there is a question of under and over representation. PhD students are the least in the list and undergraduates are the most, so there is a question of under and over-representation. How can I solve it?

Comment: Do you need each group (undergrads and PHDs) to have the same weight?

Comment: This seems to be more of a math or statistics type problem than a programming problem

Comment: The solution is to figure out how you want to address the question of over-representation: do you want to take a random sample of the PhD students and a proportional random sampling of the undergrads, or...?

Comment: I found this that would have to get you in the right direction: https://www.got-it.ai/solutions/excel-chat/excel-tutorial/random/learn-how-to-create-a-weighted-random-number-generator-in-excel

Comment: Please provide a sample it can be easier to reproduce by the people are trying to help you.

Comment: Is your goal to split the students into a bunch of groups? Or just get a list of X random students with equally represented students from each group? If the second, B1NGW ‘s answer is best.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be the fairest way would be to treat each group separately. RAND all the phDs, part time, undergraduates and postgraduates separately that way a single PhD student has a fair weighting against other PhD students only and so on and so forth.

Then RAND the result of each "winner" of PhD, Part time, undergraduate and post graduate. Then each "winner" has a 1 in 4 chance of winning overall.

Comment: What does "winner" mean? How does this address the question of representation?

Comment: Unless I am mistaken my understanding of the problem is there is a disproportionate number of students that are PhDs, postgraduates, undergraduates and part time so when using Excel to pick one at random the group with the most students in will be picked more frequently than others. My proposal is to weight each group 0.25 by picking a random student per group. Then randomly select one of those 4 students so the group with the least students in has the same chance of being picked as the biggest group

Comment: it is not completely clear what the OP wants. I realize that as a new contributor, you cannot comment unless someone comments to your answer. That is not the best gamification rule because new contributors cannot seek clarity before proposing an answer. Your approach make sense if the objective is to give each group equal weighting. I upvoted your answer - hope you get to 50 soon so that you can comment questions.

Answer (score 0):

You are right to be concerned about selection method. If the academic standard is a distinguishing factor across a mixed population, this is a possible solution.

Excel 2007 is challenging, so I will propose a solution that is a bit heavy because I am not sure I can reliably recreate that environment on my PC. If this were Excel 2019 or 365, I would not propose what I am about to present. So, this may lack elegance.

**Step 1 - Create Your Target Sample Size Table**

If you want a statistically significant sample size across each academic standing, then you would need a table that has the population size of each group (i.e. undergrad, grad, PhD, etc.) as well as a target sample size as a function of these population sizes.  Here is an example that I created to illustrate how to implement a solution. You will need a similar table with real data:

[image: sample size targets]
To create the table of target sample sizes, I used this reference: https://www.surveymonkey.com/mp/sample-size-calculator/.

You can put this anywhere you like, but I have mine in cells A1:C5 of a worksheet that I named **ref**.

**Step 2 - Separate the Students by Academic Standing**

Now you need to separate the students by academic standing. You can do this in any way that makes sense for you:

- put each group into a separate worksheet;
- put each group into a separate table on the same worksheet;
- put each group into the same table, but separate them inside the table

The main point is to keep them separated.

> This is where I am doing things differently because of my uncertainty
> of over Excel 2007. I would prefer to keep the list together, but this
> would require some large assumptions about how Excel 2007 would
> deliver the results.

To illustrate the technique, I created a column called **Academic Standing** and another with **Student ID**, imagining that you have something like this already.  I made one set of data with just PhD students, another with just Grads, etc.  You can do this however you want, but they need to be separated because of the method I will use for selection.

I then created a column next to each student row called **RandKey** that simply has the formula `=RAND()`.

[image: result]

Next to that, is a column called **Selected** that will give the result. **Selected** will have the formula: `=RANK(C2,$C$2:$C$301)<=ref!$C$2` that gives a TRUE/FALSE answer. This formula is then copied down the entire Selected column.

> NOTE: $C$2:$C$301 is the range of RandKeys for PhD students only. This
> is what I mean by keeping them separated. If the Grads were in their
> own worksheet in my example, the formula would be:
> `=RANK(C2,$C$2:$C$4301)<=ref!$C$3`. The Undergrads would be
> `=RANK(C2,$C$2:$C$12001)<=ref!$C$4` and the Part-timers would be
> `=RANK(C2,$C$2:$C$3401)<=ref!$C$5`.

This formula ranks each RandKey compared to all of the other RandKeys for the sub-population of students (PhD, Grad...). Then it looks at the table reference of Target Sample Sizes to see if that rank is <= to the target size.

In this way, you are always delivering exactly the number of students that you want to be representative of that Academic Standing population. Every time you calc (F9), it will generate a new random sample, but it will choose exactly the sample size that is statistically significant for the given population and confidence interval.

**Step 3 - Using the Results**

I am only illustrating an approach.  You can probably work out a way to make this cleaner and easier to use, but the underlying method would remain the same. It may be useful to summarize the results with a Pivot Table that reads each student data set (Student ID, Selected) and filters to show only the TRUE selections. You can double click the result and produce a list of Student ID's.

If I were to do this in Excel 365, I would keep the student data together and use dynamic arrays to generate a list of student ID's with each F9.

In any case, I hope this helps.